# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, next.js

I'm trying to change data in a JSON file from an API route in Next.js.

```
import fs from "fs/promises";
import path from "path";

export async function ReplaceData(index, data) {
  try {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "data.json");

    const existingData = await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf-8");
    const tempData = JSON.parse(existingData);

    tempData[index] = data;
    console.log("Reading Works: ", tempData);

    await fs.writeFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(tempData, null, 4));

    console.log("File successfully written!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
  }
}
```

This is my function to do this but I get the error message

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\JoMaK\OneDrive\Desktop\Website\doctor_website\data.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\JoMaK\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Website\\doctor_website\\data.json'
}
```

The `data.json` file is in the same folder but the function gets called from an API route which is not in this folder.

I already tried to change the location of the JSON file and I also tried using relative path for the file path none of it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the path of the file is correct.
I would suggest to console.log(__dirname) and then compare the same with the location of the file.

If both are at the same location, if try reading the file and logging its data.

If both the steps results correctly you will be able to write in the file. Making sure that the `filePath` is matching the file's location.

Apart from this I don't see any error in the code

Comment: Thank you for your help! I logged out the path and the problem is that the constructed path is in the .next\server\app\api\route section. Do you know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Try not having white space in the folder names. 
And if you can read the data from the same path then it will be easy for you to write on it. 

Just compare both and check